# VueJs the input value doesnt cleared with the keypress ESC the first time

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ref

I want to clear the input when i press the ESC key, the bug that i've is when i press the ESC key the first time, the input isnt cleared but when i press ESC second time it is cleard

When i display in console the value of the input after first press, it's empty but not in the UI

Here is the small piece of code that ma,age the ESC Key :

Html :

```
<input
      type="text"
      :name="context.name"
      :id="context.id"
      v-model="context.model"
      @blur="context.blurHandler"
      @keyup="getSuggestions"
      autocomplete="no"
      class="mc-text-input"
      ref="autocompleteInput"
    />
```

And the ESC event :

```
case 27: {
          console.log('Before : ' + this.$refs.autocompleteInput.value)
          this.$refs.autocompleteInput.value = ''
          console.log('After : ' + this.$refs.autocompleteInput.value)
          this.resetAutocompleteElt() // hide the autocomplete list
          break
}
```

I need to force the first ESC press to clear this input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` uses two-way binding, so you should update `context.model` instead of trying to update the element value directly, as this is likely causing your problem.

i.e. assuming you have access to `context.model` in your function that handles the event.

Replace:

```
this.$refs.autocompleteInput.value = ''
```

with:

```
this.context.model = '';
```

Comment: If i use just the second : the input was cleared but he value isnt empty, so i used the both at same time

Comment: @Tchiko It wouldn't immediately update `this.$refs.autocompleteInput.value`, it would get updated on the next DOM update.

Comment: when i use just this.context.model = ''; the value isnt cleared. I mean when i call console.log(this.$refs.autocompleteInput.value) , found the value not empty

Comment: @Tchiko Yeah, it would only update after a DOM update. For e.g. if you put your `console.log` in a `this.$nextTick` like `this.$nextTick(() => { console.log(this.$refs.autocompleteInput.value) }); ` then I reckon it would be empty.